# Refactoring Search component from App js to Search js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, components

So im following along with a book "The Road To React" By: Robin Wieruch. The book has you do everything inside the App.js file...which is extremely disappointing because this is obviously terrible practice. Anyway, ive extracted everything else to their own component files and i cant figure out how to extract the search to its own file. Ive attached an img showing the folder structure.
[image]

In App.js im trying to extract everything, leaving a return that returns the components like it should be. As it is the App.js file looks like this:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Greeting from '../Greeting/Greeting';
import Search from '../Search/Search';
import List from '../List/List';

const useSemiPersistentState = (key, initialState) => {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(
    localStorage.getItem(key) || initialState
  );

  React.useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem(key, value);
  }, [value, key]);

  return [value, setValue]
};

// App component
const App = () => {
  const stories = [
    {
      title: 'React',
      url: 'https://reactjs.org/',
      author: 'Jordan Walke',
      num_comments: 3,
      points: 4,
      objectID: 0,
    },
    {
      title: 'Redux',
      url: 'https://redux.js.org/',
      author: 'Dan Abramov, Andrew Clark',
      num_comments: 2,
      points: 5,
      objectID: 1,
    },
  ];

  // Set state on searchTerm, setSearchTerm with custom hook
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useSemiPersistentState(
    'search',
    'React'
  );

  // Get the value of search input
  const handleSearch = (event) => {
    setSearchTerm(event.target.value);
  };

  // Check if user input matches stories array
  // toLowerCase() both values
  const searchedStories = stories.filter((story) => story.title.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase())
  );

  // Render
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Greeting name="Colin" age="28" occupation="Front-end developer" />
      <InputWithLabel
        id="search"
        value={searchTerm}
        isFocused
        onInputChange={handleSearch}
      >
        <strong>Search:</strong>
      </InputWithLabel>
      <hr />
      <List list={searchedStories} />
    </div>
  );
}

// Search bar
// Destructure props search, onSearch
const InputWithLabel = ({ id, value, type = "text", onInputChange, isFocused, children, }) => {
  const inputRef = React.useRef();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (isFocused && inputRef.current) {
      inputRef.current.focus();
    }
  }, [isFocused]);

  return (
    <>
      <label htmlFor={id}>{children}</label>
      &nbsp;
      <input
        ref={inputRef}
        id={id}
        type={type}
        value={value}
        autoFocus={isFocused}
        onChange={onInputChange}
      />
    </>
  )
}

export default App;
```

The List component which is a parent of the Item component looks like so:

```
import React from 'react';
import Item from '../Item/Item';

function List({ list }) {
    return (
        <ul>
            {list.map(({ objectID, ...item }) => (
                <Item key={objectID} {...item} />
            ))}
        </ul>
    );
}

export default List;
```

The Item component looks like so:

```
import React from 'react';

function Item({ title, url, author, num_comments, points }) {
    return (
        <div>
            <li>
                <span>
                    <a href={url}>{title}</a>
                </span>
                <span> {author}</span>
                <span> {num_comments} comments,</span>
                <span> {points} points.</span>
            </li>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Item;
```

The Greeting Component and Helpers folder are unrelated in any way so i wont post them.

Just as a note all of the code in here works... and at the time im not really interested in refactoring this unless you care to. Im just trying to extract all of that nonsense that relates to what should be a separate Search component out of App.js and into Search.js. Have been trying and ive hit a wall with this as im still new with react. 

Here are the errors shown once i move all of the Search content related code from App.js to Search.js and attempt to import to the Search component into App.js
****Failed to compile**** 
src/Components/App/App.js
  Line 60:8:   'InputWithLabel' is not defined   react/jsx-no-undef
  Line 62:16:  'searchTerm' is not defined       no-undef
  Line 64:24:  'handleSearch' is not defined     no-undef
  Line 69:19:  'searchedStories' is not defined  no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

Comment: You've manage to extract the search component already right? Base on you App.js you already have imported the Search component. Also handling the search should be under search.js file and then in the search if there is a result you just have to pass the result into your list.

Comment: Hi Romeo, that import is from my attempt at extracting it from App to Search. Thats why you see that imported Search component in App, i was unsuccessful in doing it correctly though. Yes that is onpoint, i created a Search.js file to hold the entire (if possible) search related component / functions. "in the search if there is a result you just have to pass the result into your list" I think im already doing that here. <List list={searchedStories} /> But if i move everything out of App.js to Search.js list={searchedStories} doesn't recognize {searchedStories} anymore.

Comment: I suppose i should have included the errors received when removing alll of search context out of App.js to Search.js... ill work on adding this to the question now